# MSSQL function in check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create table with CHECK constraint, where CHECK calls an user defined scalar function. I have read on multiple sites that it is possible, also that it has bad performance. Even though I would like to do it.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [book_history] (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    library_id int NOT NULL,
    book_id int NOT NULL,
    borrow_time datetime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    return_policy datetime DEFAULT DATEADD(DAY, 30, GETDATE()),
    return_time datetime,
    CHECK (dbo.fn_check_duplicate(user_id, library_id, book_id) = 0)
);
```

and function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_check_duplicate
GO
CREATE FUNCTION fn_check_duplicate (@user_id int, @library_id int, @book_id int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [book_history] WHERE user_id = @user_id AND library_id = @library_id AND book_id = @book_id AND return_time IS NULL)
END
GO
```

When I try to insert new row into this `book_history` table (which is empty), I get an error saying `The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__book_history__267ABA7A". The conflict occurred in database "library", table "dbo.book_history".`

COUNT is supposed to return int data type based on MSDN documentation.
I am owner of both, the table and the function.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What rerturns: `SELECT fn_check_duplicate (user_id int, library_id int, book_id int)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to `check (dbo.fn_check_duplicate(user_id, library_id, book_id) = 1)`

The `check` is going to look at the state of the table after the insert, so you want the count to be 1.

Test it on rextester: http://rextester.com/AWDNP40594 by uncommenting the second insert.

---

You can also replace this slow check constraint with a filtered unique index like so:

```
create unique nonclustered index uix_book_history_user_library_book
  on dbo.book_history (user_id, library_id, book_id)
    where return_time is null
```

---

This might be more of what you are trying to do, if each book_id is an individual book:

```
create unique nonclustered index uix_book_history_library_book
  on dbo.book_history (library_id, book_id)
    where return_time is null
```

Because this would allow a book to only be checked out by one user at a time.

Comment: I would definitely agree that the OP should use the filtered index presented here. It is far less clunky than a scalar function.

Comment: I had no idea that CHECK is checking state after the operation. Thank you very much for this info.

Comment: About the alternative you provided: I have multiple users, which could be registered in multiple libraries, and each library has its own set of books. So you can say that combination of ``(user_id, library_id, book_id)`` is UNIQUE. But I want to prevent inserting the same ``(user_id, library_id, book_id)`` if the ``return_time`` IS NULL - that means the user still has the book borrowed. Only allow the same values to be inserted when ``return_time`` IS NOT NULL - which means that user had that book some time ago and he wants to borrow it again. Is it what the filtered unique index does?

Comment: @Lopfest you might also find this interesting: http://rextester.com/XXW89099 failed inserts consume an `id`. so if a failed insert would have had and id of 2, then the next successful insert will have an id of 3.

Comment: @Lopfest My last alternative without the `user_id` in the index was in regard to the situation where: if a `book_id` is one physical object, then it would be fair to say that two users couldn't both have the same physical object checked out at the same time.  But if a `book_id` just represents an edition of a book or a title or etc. and there are many, then that wouldn't apply.

Comment: @SqlZim the first alternative applies to my situation. I also didn't know there are any filtered indexes. I'm kind of new to mssql. Thanks for all these valuable info